# Concatenation in a linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

```
string test = "/";
var results = from table1 in data2.AsEnumerable()
              join table2 in data1.AsEnumerable()
              on ((string)(table1["ANo"]) + test + (string)table1["MNo"]) equals (string)table2["File_Code"]
              where (float)table1["c1"] != 0
              && (string)table1["Case_Status"] == "Open"
              select new
              {
                  ACode = (int)table1["ACode"],
                  ANo = (int)table1["ANo"],
                  c1 = (int)table1["c1"]
              };
```

Getting a error:

> Specified Cast is invalid on ((string)(table1["ANo"]) + test + (string)table1["MNo"]) equals (string)table2["File_Code"].

So in my linq I am trying to match `ANo`/`MNo` in one database to `File_Code` in another where `ANo` & `MNo` are different columns in the first database, any ideas?

Comment: Are ANo, MNo, and File_Code all string fields? And could any be null?

Comment: What is in `data1` and `data2`? That's probably going to be quite important to answer the question :) Note that you have to use `.ToString()` instead of `(string)` if the data isn't actually a string, but rather a number for example. `(string)` does a cast, if possible, while `.ToString()` does a conversion, two very different things.

Comment: data2 is a table in a access database while data1 is from a mssql database.

Comment: @Luaan I only see your comment now (after answering myself). If you convert :) it into an answer I think that should get accepted.

Comment: @GertArnold I like your answer, it's simple and straight to the point. No reason to add another answer of mine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var results1 = from table1 in data2.AsEnumerable()
                       select new
                       {
                           A_M = table1["ANo"] + "\" + table1["MatterNo"],
                           ANo = table1["ANo"],
                           c1 = table1["c1"].Equals(DBNull.Value) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(table1["c1"]),
                           //Case_Status = Convert.ToString(table1["Case_ Status"])
                       };
        var results = from table1 in results1
                      join table2 in data1.AsEnumerable()
                      on table1.A_M equals (string)table2["File_Code"]
                      where table1.c1 != 0
                      && (string)table2["Case_Status"] == "Open"
                      orderby table1.ANo
                      select new
                      {
                          cCode = table2["acAccountCode"],
                          ANo = table1.ANo,
                          c1 = table1.c1
                      };
```

Comment: Now my next challenge to somehow convert this IEnum to a datatable Data row Array.

Answer (score 2):

(string)(table1["ANo"]) is actually a call to a conversion function in .NET, and there is no corresponding function in the underlying storage engine. Therefore, when LINQ provider is about to actualize the query in form of a particular storage-specific expression tree, the operation fails because LINQ provider cannot find an appropriate function which to use.

If item such as ANo is not already a string (e.g. varchar or something similar), then you probably need to call specific provider's method such as SqlFunctions.StringConvert(table1["ANo").

Typical examples where .NET code cannot be converted by the LINQ provider are date/time functions (e.g. DateTime.AddSeconds, etc.).

Comment: The two `.AsEnumerable()` calls turn this in a pure linq-to-objects case.

Comment: Be cautious with that - converting data tables to enumerable means bringing the cross join to memory before cutting them by the join condition. Results should be converted to objects (and subdued to LINQ to objects afterwards) only after the storage has done the best it can to construct the minimum of records that are really needed.

Answer (score 2):

When you've got code like

```
object a = "1";
var a2 = (string)a;
```

You're only changing the *compile-time type* of `a` from `object` to `string`, which is called casting. This only works because `a` already *is* a string (the *actual type*). If you do

```
object a = 1;
var a2 = (string)a;
```

You run into a runtime exception (`InvalidCastException`) because an integer can't act as (cast to) a `string`. That's what's going on in your code. At least one of the objects you try to cast to string is not actually a string.

The remedy is simple: use `ToString()`. This *converts* the object to a string. Conversion converts the *actual* type of an object.